# Change fragment by Click on Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I want to change of `Fragment` inside an `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView` (while using `CardView`).

Here is my `ViewHolder`:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

private TextView textViewView;
private ImageView imageView;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textViewView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
}

public void bind(MyObject myObject){
    textViewView.setText(myObject.getText());
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
        .load(myObject.getImageUrl())
        .centerCrop()
        .fit()
        .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: But what is your problem ? Why are you coming here ? What are you asking ?

Comment: pardon, what is your question again

Comment: How can I change the fragment ?